# How to configure VUZIX Blade Hardware Profile in AVD Manager?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, vuzix

I am trying to setup the VUZIX developer environment to create the first working prototype. The source code which I found on the VUZIX website is here: https://www.vuzix.com/Developer/Dashboard/Blade-Code-Samples

Unfortunately there are no readymade profiles for VUZIX Blade in Android Virtual Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the xml profile from here: https://vuzix-website.s3.amazonaws.com/files/Content/Upload/vuzix-blade_v3.xml

Further step-by-step instructions can be found here:
https://www.vuzix.com/Developer/KnowledgeBase/Detail/1066

Comment: I get access denied ...

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>6D2RPQB7MY3QNQPW</RequestId>
<HostId>ekrwnWR0l5jW/Ks7CWCk7f6NIDUnC1g6pu4TiJdhkynM2lM449SJnTsOVPnyR66mVz7NaezXCvQ=</HostId>
</Error>